# How to calculate the number of childern in a tree using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have designed a recursive algorithm to find the number of children in a string. The string is actually an array such as [1,0,1,0,1]. There three possible children of this string which are [0,0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,0,1] and [1,0,1,0,0]. Thus the criteria for creating the children is to decrement only one non-zero entry in the string. Since there are three non-zero entries in [1,0,1,0,1] so three possible children. Continuing in this fashion each children can now have two possible children and so on. The recursion stop when there is only one non-zero entry in the string.

This is my code:

```
public class Recursion {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] c={1,0,1,0,1};
        System.out.println(num(c)); 
    }

    private static int num(int[] v){
        if(numChildren(v)==1){ 
            return 1;
        }    
        else{
            int[][] ge=children(v);
            for(int[] e:ge){
            return 1+num(e);
            }
            System.out.print("this return should never execute");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static int numChildren(int[] val){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
            if(val[i]!=0){
                sum+=1;
            }   
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int[][] children(int[] p){
        int pChildern=numChildren(p);
        int[] d=new int[pChildern];
        int[][] r=new int[pChildern][];
        int c=0;
        for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++){
            if(p[j]!=0){
                d[c]=j;
                c++;
            }    
        }

        for(int i=0;i<pChildern;i++){
            p[d[i]]--;
            r[i]=p.clone();
            p[d[i]]++;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

My code does execute but doesn't produce correct result. It should print 6 but it prints 3.

Can any one suggest me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Returns size of subtree including the root
int getNumChilds(Node node) {
    int count = 1;
    for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
        count += getNumChilds(child);
    }        
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I don't have balance tree that include right and left children

Comment: I would be happy if you use the getter instead the field `children`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really go into details, but this block looks weird:

```
int[][] ge=children(v);
for(int[] e:ge){
    return 1+num(e);
}
System.out.print("this return should never execute");
return 0;
```

You want to sum up all its children here, but you return too early. It should be something like this:

```
int[][] ge=children(v);
int totChild = 0;
for(int[] e:ge){
    totChild = totChild + num(e);
}

return totChild;
```

Comment: You are write I made this mistake. However even after correction the result is not valid. For instance the number of possible children for [4,4,1,1,1] are 200. but the code produce 69300 which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code might be well suited to your needs.

{1, 0, 1, 0, 1} --> gives 7 (2 x 2 x 2 - 1)

{1, 1, 1, 1, 1} --> gives 31 (2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 - 1)

{4, 4, 1, 1, 1} --> gives 199 (5 x 5 x 2 x 2 x 2 - 1)

-1 is to remove {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} from children.

```
public class Recursion {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] c={4,4,1,1,1};
        System.out.println(num(c, 0)); 
    }

    private static void print(int[] v) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for ( int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i ) {
            System.out.print(v[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("] ");
    }

    private static int num(int[] v, int k){
        if(numChildren(v)==1){ 
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            int r = 1;
            for ( int i = k; i < v.length; ++i ) {
                if ( v[i] > 0) {
                    int o = v[i];
                    v[i] = o - 1;
                    print(v);
                    r += num(v, i);
                    v[i] = o;
                }
            }
            return r;
        }
    }

    private static int numChildren(int[] val){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
            if(val[i]!=0){
                sum+=1;
            }   
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```